# Javascript breaking when adding Google Analytics ga function

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I have been trying to get this code to work:

```
if(searchResults != null){
    for(var i=0; i < searchResults.length; i++){
        var file = nlapiLoadFile(searchResults[i].getValue('custrecord_download_file'));
        var result = searchResults[i].getText('custrecord_download_name');
        var analytics = "onclick=\"ga(\'send\',\'event\','" + result + "');\"";
        ulText += '<li><a href="'+ file.getURL() + '" target="_blank" ' + analytics + ' >' + searchResults[i].getText('custrecord_download_name') + '</a></li>';
    }
}

ulText += '</ul>';
response.write('document.write(\'' + ulText + '\')');
```

}

But it breaks when it reaches the analytics variable since it has parameters with apostrophes. In the inspector I recieve:

```
document.write('<ul><li><a href="/core/media/media.nl?id=339181&c=685553&h=20e8a29160195ea985c6&_xt=.pdf" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send','event','Product Datasheet')" >Product Datasheet</a></li></ul>')
```

How can I still get the ga function working with 'send' like Google Analytics asks for without the script breaking once it reaches the first ga parameter. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: if you want to send the strings send and event, try `\\\'send\\\', \\\'event\\\', '`" + result + "'

Answer (score 0):

Escape your string with backlash like this:

```
document.write('<ul><li><a href="/core/media/media.nl?id=339181&c=685553&h=20e8a29160195ea985c6&_xt=.pdf" target="_blank"  onclick="ga(\'send\',\'event\',\'Product Datasheet\')">Product Datasheet</a></li></ul>')
```

It should work and these could be a helpful: [Escape strings in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp)

Comment: Hey Rocky, I have actually done that with no luck as it still writes it out exactly the same. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var analytics = "onclick=\"ga(\'send\',\'event\',\'" + result + "\');\"";
```

Or you could try in ES6:

```
const analytics = `onclick=\"ga(\'send\',\'event\',\'${result}\');\"`;
```

Comment: Hm, I just tried it but still comes back the same way. It looks like [this](https://i.sli.mg/NKvwuC.png). I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Did You try making it inline?

    `ulText += '<li><a href="'+ file.getURL() + '" target="_blank" onclick="ga(\'send\',\'event\',\'' + result + '\'); >' + searchResults[i].getText('custrecord_download_name') + '</a></li>';`